# Tree with $k$ edges is a subgraph of any graph with all vertices of degree $\geq k$.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Let $T$ be a tree with $k$ edges. Let $G$ be a graph where every vertex has a degree of at least $k$. Show that $T$ is a subgraph $G$.

I know this implies that in a graph where every vertex is at least $k$, you can find a copy of every tree with $k$ edges, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: @hardmath fixed the title

Comment: Okay, but let me fix a bit further...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Induction on $k$ (deleting a leaf to apply the induction hypothesis).

Comment: Please clarify, at least as to the proposition and its base case for induction.

Comment: @hardmath I meant the question in the body of the post, if that's what you were asking?

Comment: What do you mean by "leaf" in such context? The original graph G has a leaf only if its lesser degree is 1.

Comment: @user137227 Given a fixed $T$ with $k$ edges, delete a leaf to get a new tree $T^\prime$ with $k-1$ edges. Notice that $G$ also has minimum degree at least $k-1$ since $G$ has minimum degree at least $k$, so $T^\prime$ is a subgraph of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough idea; I'll leave you to fill in the details.

We proceed algorithmically.

Pick a vertex $u$ in $T$ and map it to a vertex $\varphi(u)$ in $G$.  Mark $u$ as "mapped" and $\varphi(u)$ as "used".

While there are unmapped vertices in $T$, pick a vertex $x$ in $T$ that is a neighbor of a mapped vertex $w$.  Map it to a vertex $\varphi(x)$ in $G$ that is an unused neighbor of $\varphi(w)$.  Mark $x$ as "mapped" and $\varphi(x)$ as "used".

What remains is to check (a) $\varphi(x)$ always exists, and (b) if $ab$ is an edge in $T$ then $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ is an edge in $G$.